# "do" in "do Application.Run(form)" sentence

Tags: f#

What is the difference between

```
do Application.Run(form)
```

and, simply:

```
Application.Run(form) ?
```

What is the role of `do` keyword in the first sentence?

Answer (score 5):

Whereas 'do' was a required keyword in many places in the language in some of the earlier releases, nowadays you rarely need 'do'.  The remaining exceptions that I can think of are that 'do' is still part of loop syntax (e.g. "while e1 do e2") and if you want to put an assembly-level attribute or an attribute on the startup method, you can put the attribute before the explicit 'do' of a final code block in a module.  Often times in F# samples you'll see

```
[<STAThread>]
do Application.Run(form)
```

as the last two lines of a file, and I think the 'do' is still required there in order to be able to attach the attribute on the line above it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a holdover - like how you can still CALL a sub or SET a variable instead of just doing those things directly, as in:

```
SET varname = 5
CALL mysub()
```

Versus just:

```
varname = 5
mysub()
```

In other words, I don't think it matters, and the compiler just discards it.

Comment: interesting, but do you have any idea what it is a holdover to? Its not like F# is an old language

Comment: As a complete guess, as a marker for expressions with side-effect as in Haskell http://www.zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputsyntax/doQexpressions_reference.html

Comment: @Bob: F# has been around for a few years, originally as a project from Microsoft Research.  The language has changed/simplified a bit during that time.

Comment: Ah - it seems that it's leftover from an earlier release of the compiler, as well as just being general programming syntax in a number of other languages, so maybe it's just there for ease of reading it.

Comment: Not to mention it's OCaml compat/history?